# how to have a dynamic text label with a loading bar

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

The last time I worked with .net was the 2.0 days. I've decided to pick it up to develop some Store/WP apps. Currently I've gotten the code part done, ie all my classes that do all the work but I am having trouble with the XAML/UI.

Basically I have a HUB control. In one of the hub sections (the first one), I need to have a control that needs to be updated as soon as the app is launched. This control (whether its a checkbox or a textblock) checks whether they can use the app. For all intents and purposes, this is done by a function that returns true/false.

So basically, when I launch the app I want this control to show a "loading.gif checking if you have your account enabled". While this is happening, my function is run and based on its return (true/false) I want it to say "Sorry, you can not access" or "Yes you can access".

What is the best control for doing this? A textblock seems like what I need, but can I add a gif in there?

Some additional info:
1) I will use a sleep function to delay the function for a couple of seconds. This is for UI purpose only.

2) I want the other hub sections to be disabled while my function checks (again, it should be a matter of milliseconds based on connection speed) but the other sections should be disabled.

3) In addition, if someone can point to me some good examples of XAML code or tutorials, that would be helpful.

Edit: looks like I can use a ProgressRing Control

Comment: You've got your requirements detailed, but have you tried anything yet? So far I see a public bool and a notification of a property change, the images and text you could display a number of ways. Like just a bool for your status thingy, bind it to the Visibility of your yes/sorry stuff appropriately and the IsEnabled state of your Hub control.

Comment: That's what I am currently programming in. However, I am just overwhelmed with the convolution of all the controls and the properties they have. I think I seem to have an okay solution with the progressring control. What should I do in terms of this question? answer it myself or delete it?

Comment: You may be over-complicating it. Share what's not working for you so folks can help sort it out.